# Nested container in c++

Tags: c++, vector, stl, nested

**I am new to C++ concepts,I am very much confused in inserting a value in a nested container.**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<vector<vector<vector<vector<int>>>>>s;
    s[0][0][0][0].push_back(5);
    return 0;
}
```

**My program gets terminated abnormally.**

Comment: `s[0]` doesn't exist until you create it. Once it does, `s[0][0]` still doesn't exist. And so on...

Comment: start with a non nested vector. A nested vector then works the same

Comment: It is very infrequent to actually need this depth. What are you trying to do? This sounds like a case where an associative container and a 4-element key might be a better solution

Answer (score 3):

You've default initialised `s`. The default constructor of vector creates an **empty** vector.

`s[0]` accesses the first element of the vector. An empty vector has no elements. This is a contradiction. The behaviour of accessing elements outside the bounds of the vector is undefined.

You could initialise a non-empty vector for example like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>>> s
{ // std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>>>
    { //         std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>>
        { //                 std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>
            { //                         std::vector<std::vector<int>>
                {5}, //                              std::vector<int>
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert elements to each vectors before accesing. Otherwise, you will wrongly access to a nonexistent element.

```cpp
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
int main()
{
    vector<vector<vector<vector<vector<int>>>>>s;
    s.push_back(vector<vector<vector<vector<int>>>>());
    s[0].push_back(vector<vector<vector<int>>>());
    s[0][0].push_back(vector<vector<int>>());
    s[0][0][0].push_back(vector<int>());
    s[0][0][0][0].push_back(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or just `vector<vector<vector<vector<vector<int>>>>>s{{{{{5}}}}};` and remove the `push_back()` call?

Answer (score 1):

Either stick with vector and follow [eerorika's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68484144/5470596) or choose a container default-constructing elements upon access, like [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

```
#include <map> // don't use stdc++.h or using namespace std
int main()
{
    template<class T>
    using map = std::map<std::size_t, T>;

    map<map<map<map<map<int>>>>> s;
    s[0][0][0][0][0] = 5;
}
```